# Подключение less

Tags: css, less

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>site</title>
<meta charset="cn-1251" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

хочу подключить less

```
@color: #ccc;

body{
background: @color;
}
```

не могу запустить на google chrome

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/136525/

Comment: так я туда заходил!
у меня что не так как там не могу понять!!

Comment: у меня что не так????
туда я и без Вас заходил перед тем как задать вопрос

Comment: если кого интересует, проблема біла в том что встроеній компилятор есть только у firefox

Comment: Чтоб все работало в хроме, его нужно запустить с ключом --allow-file-access-from-files
 В строке объект в свойствах ярлыка хрома. Через пробел. Т.е. должно быть, например, так "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files

 И, соответственно, запускать через этот ярлык.

Comment: Окончательный ответ такой: 
надо добавить к строке пути к ярлыку Google Chrome --disable-web-security & -–allow-file-access-from-files (перед добавлением пробел)

Answer (score 1):

LESS просто так не подключаеться как стандартный CSS

1. Качаем скрипт - LESSCSS.ORG
2. Подключаем его к HTML - две строчки кода:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less">
   <script src="less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
3. (можем писать на less, только не в Хром)

   Качаем Winless - WINLESS.ORG
4. Устанавливаем и конвертируем наш style.less > style.css (В папке
   проекта должно получиться 2 файла .less и .css)
5. В код добавляем +1 строчку:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   ```
6. Результат:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="style.less">
   <script src="less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

И работает в Chrome! (если туго объяснил: гуглим, хабрим, тостим и т.д)

Comment: Если добавлена строчка в пункте 5, то зачем нужны две следующие за ней строчки?

Comment: Оу, спасибо не заметил, немного тофтология получаеться.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще порядок должен быть другой - сначала подключаем скрипт, а потом файл less.
По ссылке в комментариях тоже так.

А вообще, попробуйте какой-нибудь компилятор локальный. Типа проги WinLess.
Тут вот на обожаемом вебрефе есть о ней статья - https://webref.ru/layout/less/compile/winless